# How to resolve: ''A TOP N or FETCH rowcount value may not be negative''

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Referring to my earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52481827/group-by-sum-of-values-with-missing-months) - which works perfectly fine when executed within SQL Server Management Studio, I keep getting the A TOP N or FETCH rowcount value may not be negative error when I try to execute it within C# code with entity framework. The code I use is;

```
    var sDate = "20180925"; // DateTime.Now.AddMonths(NoOfMonthsBack).ToString("yyyyMMdd");
    var eDate = "20180101"; //DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");


var result =  ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("; WITH d(d) AS ( SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, n, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @StartDate), 0)) " +
                                              "FROM ( SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(MONTH, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1) n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) - 1 FROM sys.all_objects " +
                                              "ORDER BY [object_id] ) AS n ) SELECT [Period] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), YEAR(d.d)) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), MONTH(d.d)), QtyTotal = ISNULL(SUM(o.QEXIT),0) " +
                                              "FROM d LEFT OUTER JOIN VE_STOCKTRANS AS o ON o.TRANSDATE >= d.d and STOCKID = @pID AND TRANSTYPE = @TransType AND o.TRANSDATE < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, d.d) " +
                                              "GROUP BY d.d ORDER BY d.d;",
                                              new SqlParameter("@StartDate", sDate),
                                              new SqlParameter("@EndDate", eDate),
                                              new SqlParameter("@pID", pID),
                                              new SqlParameter("@TransType", transType));
```

I would be grateful if someone with the experience could show me the right direction in order to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Ummm, just make sure that @startDate is always earlier than @endDate???  Your example has a start of 25th September 2018, and an end of 1st January 2018.  Why are you specifying parameters that go backwards through time???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `NoOfMonthsBack` is a positive value (e.g. `int` or `float`). You should use it **negated** if your goal is to go back in time. From the comment in the first line:

```
var sDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-NoOfMonthsBack).ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Comment: Yes, actually this question should be deleted as the problem was with the wrong parameter values that I provide into the function. Thank you anyway for making me realize.

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(MONTH, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)` is giving a negative, or could potentially do so

Wrap it with an `abs()` to guarantee a positive number:

```
SELECT TOP abs(DATEDIFF(MONTH, @StartDate, @EndDate)) + 1
```

Comment: @usr Shhhh... Stealth edit went in... You're right though, the abs should only apply to the date diff, and not the whole calculation.

Comment: My point was that if you take a negative number that results from a bug and then just flip it to become positive that number would still not be what the OP wants, right? It's a random number which now just happens to not crash. The OP should fix the bug that causes a negative number to be produced in the first place.

Comment: @JohnHC if you look at the whole script (not just the SQL) you'll see that the bug is providing a start that is after the stop.

Comment: @MatBailie Aye, but I hadn't spotted that when I popped this anwer up. Still semi-valid, mind, and offers another option in case someone else has a similar issue in future.